# Passing multiple arguments to cmd

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping, arguments, simple-html-dom

I have been working on a program that would scrape the following website - https://filmstoon.in/

So far, I managed to make the code take variables (with `$argv`) and separate series from movies. However, I wish for my code to take multiple arguments at once and execute the code.

So if I were to type `php final.php "iron man" "spider man" "expendables 3"` it would execute the code. Code:

```
include  ("simple_html_dom.php");
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Vilnius');
$linkMovies = "https://filmstoon.in/?s=".getArgumentValues($argv, "+");
$linkSeries = "https://filmstoon.in/series/".getArgumentValues($argv, "-");

//argv with sepe

function getArgumentValues($argv, $seperator){
$values = "$argv[1]";
  foreach($argv as $key=>$value){
    if($key>1){
      $values.="$seperator$value";
      }
    }
return $values;
}

//Movies

function get_content_movies($linkMovies, $argv){
    $htmlContent = file_get_contents($linkMovies);
    $argvValue = getArgumentValues($argv, " ");
    if(!preg_match("/href\=\"(.*?)\".*?oldtitle\=\"$argvValue/i", $htmlContent, $search)){
      return null;
    };
    $key = array_values($search)[1];
    $htmlContent = file_get_contents($key);
    if(preg_match("/series/", $key)){
      main();
    }
    else{
    preg_match('/\<h3 itemprop\=\"name\"\>(.*)<\/h3>/iSU', $htmlContent, $title);
    preg_match('/<iframe.*data-lazy-src=\"(.*)\".*><\/iframe>/iSU', $htmlContent, $embed_url);
    preg_match('/<meta.*property="og:url".*content="(.*)".*\/>/iSU', $htmlContent, $meta_url);
    $date = date('m/d/Y H:i', time());
    echo "{$date} \t {$embed_url[1]} \t {$meta_url[1]} \t {$title[1]} \n";
    $result = array($date, $embed_url[1], $meta_url[1], $title[1]);
    $output = 'scrape.txt';
    file_put_contents($output, print_r($result, true), FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
get_content_movies($linkMovies, $argv);

//TV Series

class episode{
  private $title;
  private $host_url;
  private $linking_url;
  public function setTitle($title){
    $this->title = $title;
  }
  public function getTitle(){
    return $this->title;
  }
  public function setHost_url($host_url){
    $this->host_url = $host_url;
  }
  public function getHost_url(){
    return $this->host_url;
  }
  public function setLinking_url($linking_url){
    $this->linking_url = $linking_url;
  }
  public function getLinking_url(){
    return $this->linking_url;
  }
}

function main(){
  $array_url = getting_url();
  foreach($array_url as $single_link){
    $episodeObject = info_from_linking($single_link);
    echo_to_server($episodeObject->getLinking_url(), $episodeObject->getHost_url(),  $episodeObject->getTitle());
    writeToFile($episodeObject->getLinking_url(), $episodeObject->getHost_url(),  $episodeObject->getTitle());
  }
}

function getting_url(){
  global $linkSeries;
  $html = file_get_html($linkSeries);
  $array_url = array();
  foreach($html->find('.les-content a') as $divClass) {
    $linking_url = $divClass->href;
    array_push($array_url, $linking_url);
  }
  return $array_url;
}

function info_from_linking($episode_link){
  $inside_linking = file_get_html($episode_link);
  $mainDiv = $inside_linking->find('div[class="main-content main-detail"]')[0];
  $title = $mainDiv->find('h3[itemprop="name"]',0)->plaintext;
  $host_url = $mainDiv->find('iframe',1)->src;
  $class = new episode;
  $class->setTitle($title);
  $class->setHost_url($host_url);
  $class->setLinking_url($episode_link);
  return $class;
}

function echo_to_server($linking_url, $host_url, $title){
  $date = date('m/d/Y H:i', time());
  echo "{$date} \t {$linking_url} \t {$host_url} \t {$title} \n";
}

function writeToFile($linking_url, $host_url, $title){
  $date = date('m/d/Y H:i', time());
  $result = array($date, $linking_url, $host_url, $title);
  $output = 'scrape.txt';
  file_put_contents($output, print_r($result, true), FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Just an FYI, since this is an education work for my self improvement (I am quite new to programming), I used dom parsing and regex together just to test it out.

Comment: I haven't digged into your code but.. Isn't that what you already do by looping `$argv`? In fact you've written code to explicitly join them again :-?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, the loop for $argv just makes the search in the link (https://filmstoon.in/?s=, https://filmstoon.in/series/) add " ", "-" or "+". Basically it's a separator so that you wouldn't have to write ```php final.php iron-man``` or ```php final.php game-of-thrones```, instead just write with blank spaces, as you would normally do when searching for something in a search bar.

Comment: I don't understand your objective here. Can you provide an example with the desired behavior?

Comment: Sure, I'll try my best to explain.

Right now, the script only executes if you provide it one argument in the cmd line. So, for example, if I execute the code with ```php final.php iron man```, it will execute the code as it should.

But if I want more than one argument in the cmd line for the code to execute, for example ```php final.php "iron man" "spider man" "expendables 3"```, it will not work.

My objective is to make the cmd line take more than one argument so it would execute the code with multiple arguments. For example if I want to scrape 3 movies, I want to enter 3 arguments.

Comment: I suppose you would start by making `$separator` be the first argument, then you would use the splat operator to unpack one or more arguments into a single variable so that you could iterate it.  I am finding your question a little bit Too Broad.  Please try to narrow the exact part that you need to fix.  The code dump is a little bit too big to be considered a [mcve].